# What is this colon doing in this python expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I ran into a bug in my code earlier today when I accidentally used the colon operator while trying to assign values in a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['a'] = 1  # Puts value 1 under key 'a', as expected
my_dict['b'] : 2  # Valid syntax, does nothing
```

The syntax was valid so the code executed just fine. But I have never seen this syntax before. What is that last line doing? I am in python3.11.

Comment: See https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#annotating-expressions